# Change the font of number in section

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I need to change the font of the number of the sections without changing the font of the name of section.

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{article}
\sectionfont{\color{sec}\fontsize{16}{16}\FZzzh\selectfont}
```

The result is:

> 1. section A

in the same font of FZzzh

The ideal output should be 1.(Arial) section A(FZzzh)

Comment: Does the font for the sectioning number have to be Arial, or can it be any sans-serif font? If it has to be Arial, how do you load this font? E.g., do you employ either XeLateX or LuaLaTeX and provide an instruction such as `\setsansfont{Arial}` in the preamble? How is the "sec" color defined? How is the the `\FZzzh` macro defined?

Comment: Hi, Mico. I am not quite experienced of latex. I am not clear about the question of loading Arial font. Is there supposed to be a problem of loading this font? I am using Xelatex. I got \setmainfont{Arial} in the preamble. "sec" is a color defined as "\definecolor{sec}{RGB}{0,80,143}". \FZzzh is a chinese font defined by "\newfontfamily\FZzzh{"方正正准黑简体"}".

Comment: Thanks for this additional information. There's no problem with "Arial". I just wanted to make sure that you wanted this particular font. Some people tend to use "Arial" almost as a synonym for "any sans-serif font", and I wanted to find out how you use the term. Thanks for providing more information about the color "sec". I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't make use of any particular LaTeX package. The code assumes that either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is in use. I didn't make use of the `\FZzzh` instruction that's in your example code, though, as I don't have the font in question on my system.

The point of this method is that cross-references to section numbers, elsewhere in the document, will continue to be typeset in the ambient text font, rather than in the particular sans-serif font and color that's desired for the sectioning number in the section headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sec}{RGB}{0,80,143}

\makeatletter  % see, e.g., p. 26 of "The LaTeX Companion"
  \def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
     {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%   default setting
     {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% individual control
  }
  \def\section@cntformat{\color{sec}\textsf{\thesection}\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{In the beginning} \label{sec:beginning}

\section{Later on the same day}

As we showed in section \ref{sec:beginning}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With `titlesec` this is very easy. Do either

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\textsf{\textcolor{sec}{\thesection}}}    %% change here
{1em}
{}
```

or simply

```
\titlelabel{\textsf{\textcolor{sec}{\thetitle}}\quad}
```

This will change the format of label for all sectioning levels.

Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sec}{RGB}{0,80,143}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%% this
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\textsf{\textcolor{sec}{\thesection}}}{1em}{}
%% or
%\titlelabel{\textsf{\textcolor{sec}{\thetitle}}\quad}   %% this affects section, subsection etc
\begin{document}
\section{In the beginning}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the `\titlelabel` instruction affect the appearance of the sectioning number at all sectioning levels? If so, it may be a fact worth pointing out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what about changing the color of the numbers?

Comment: @sibscc Please see the update.

Comment: @Mico: That is why the warning attached! :-) Or I will better remove that sentence.